# UIImageView userInteractionEnabled not changing

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob

I have created an `Ad` `view` in my `App`. I have an "x" (exit) image in my `Ad view` (I'm using Google's adMob).

When the `Ad` is loaded normally everything is ok. But when there is an error and the `Ad` cant load I want to display my own `Ad`, I have implemented the following method:

```
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error{
    cloaseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    shibbyAdImage.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"Failed to load Ad with error : %@", error);
}
```

And for some reason the `userInteractionEnabled` isn't setting to yes...

Just some more code that might help :

This is called to load the `Ad`-

```
-(void)googleAd{

    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle];
    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

    //[bannerView_ setDelegate:self];    
    bannerView_.delegate = self;
    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    NSLog(@"in googleAd");
}
```

And placing the `Ad` -

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"BannerSlide" context:nil];
    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                      self.view.frame.size.width/2 -
                                      bannerView.frame.size.width/2,
                                      self.view.frame.size.height/2 -
                                      bannerView.frame.size.height/2,
                                      bannerView.frame.size.width,
                                      bannerView.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
//    NSLog(@"in adViewDidReceiveAd");
//    NSLog(@"adpoint x: %g y: %g",adPoint.x, adPoint.y);
    cloaseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you `NSLog` the value of `userInteractionEnabled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first set the usrInteraction, log it:

```
cloaseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
NSLog(@"UserInteraction should now be on, its %d", cloaseView.userInteractionEnabled);
```

same with:

```
cloaseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

You may need to walk up the view chain (up the superviews) to see if some view is blocking userInteraction:

You can use this to do that (by adding a button or calling it from a timer when all should be OK:

```
@implementation UIView (Utilities)

+ (void)dumpSuperviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    while(v) {
        [self appendView:v toStr:str];
        v = v.superview;
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    LTLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}
+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)a toStr:(NSMutableString *)str
{
    [str appendFormat:@"  %@: frame=%@ bounds=%@ layerFrame=%@ tag=%d userInteraction=%d alpha=%f hidden=%d\n", 
        NSStringFromClass([a class]),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.frame),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.bounds),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.layer.frame),
        a.tag, 
        a.userInteractionEnabled,
        a.alpha,
        a.isHidden
        ];
}

@end
```